# Margins created with pivot_table have issues with Period datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large (+10m rows) dataframe with three columns: sales dates (dtype: `datetime64[ns]`), customer names and sales per customer. Sales dates include day, month and year in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` (i.e. 2019-04-19). I discovered the pandas `to_period` function and like to use the `period[A-MAR]` dtype. As the business year (ending in March) is different from the calendar year that is exactly what I was looking for. With the `to_period` function I am able to assign the respective sales dates to the correct business year while avoiding to create new columns with additional information.

I convert the date column as follows:

```
df_input['Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_input['Date']).to_period("A-MAR")
```

Now a peculiar issue arrises when I use `pivot_table` to aggregate the data and set `margins=True`. The `aggfunc` returns the correct values in the output table. However, the results in the last row (total value, created by the margins) are wrong as `NaN` is shown (or in my case a 0 as I set `fill_value = 0`). The function I use:

```
df_output = df_input.pivot_table(index="Customer", 
     columns = "Date",
     values = "Sales",
     aggfunc ={"Sales": np.sum},
     fill_value = 0, 
     margins= True)
```

When I do not convert the dates to a period but use a simple year (integer) instead, the margins are calculated correctly and no NaN appears in the last row of the pivot output table.

I searched all over the internet but could not find a solution that was working. I would like to keep working with the period datatype and just need the margins to be calculated correctly. I hope someone can help me out here. Thank you!